# Lambda implement transactions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We created a lambda which moves messages from DL SQS Queue to SQS Queue (target) on a schedule basis. As part of that I want to implement transactions.

Basically copying message to target Queue and then delete message in DL queue (source). But in any case after copying message to target queue, and fails to delete message in source queue, the message should be deleted from target queue.

Here is my source Code

```
import json
import boto3
import sys
import sys

def get_messages_from_queue(sqs_client, queue_url, max_message_count):
    """Generates messages from an SQS queue.
    Note: this continues to generate messages until the queue is empty.
    Every message on the queue will be deleted.
    :param queue_url: URL of the SQS queue to read.
    See https://alexwlchan.net/2018/01/downloading-sqs-queues/
    """
    processed_message_count = 0

    while processed_message_count < max_message_count:
        #print("Max Mesage Count: " + str(max_message_count))
        remaining_message_count = max_message_count - processed_message_count
        #print("Remaining messages: " + str(remaining_message_count))

        receive_message_count = min(10, remaining_message_count)
        get_resp = sqs_client.receive_message(
            QueueUrl=queue_url, AttributeNames=["All"], MaxNumberOfMessages=receive_message_count
        )

        #print("Actual response:")
        #print(get_resp)

        try:
            #print("Number of messages receieved: " + str(len(get_resp["Messages"])))
            yield from get_resp["Messages"]
        except KeyError:
            return

        entries = [
            {"Id": msg["MessageId"], "ReceiptHandle": msg["ReceiptHandle"]}
            for msg in get_resp["Messages"]
        ]

        resp = sqs_client.delete_message_batch(QueueUrl=queue_url, Entries=entries)

        if len(resp["Successful"]) != len(entries):
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Failed to delete messages: entries={entries!r} resp={resp!r}"
            )
        
        processed_message_count += len(get_resp["Messages"])
        print("After deleting, number of processed messages are: " + str(processed_message_count))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        max_message_count = event['MSG_TRANSFER_LIMIT']
        src_queue_url = event["SRC_QUEUE_URL"]
        dst_queue_url = event["DEST_QUEUE_URL"]

        if src_queue_url == dst_queue_url:
            sys.exit("Source and destination queues cannot be the same.")

        sqs_client = boto3.client("sqs")

        #while processed_message_count < max_message_count:
            

        for message in get_messages_from_queue(sqs_client, src_queue_url, max_message_count):
            response = sqs_client.send_message(QueueUrl=dst_queue_url, MessageBody=message["Body"])
            print(json.loads(message["Body"]['records'][0]))
            #print(response)

        return {
            'ProcessedMessageCount': max_message_count
        }
```

Comment: You never call `lambda_handler`. Why is it nested inside `get_messages_from_queue`?

Comment: Are you saying that your code (as shown) works fine, but you want some hints on how to implement "Delete from target if I couldn't delete form Source"?

Comment: yes, you are right, i want to implement some kind of transaction

Comment: @barmar where (in while line) did you see lambda_handler inside get_messages_from_queue?

Comment: From the indentation. `def get_messages_from_queue` is at the left margin, `def lambda_handler` is indented. Was that was a copying error?

Comment: Yes it's a typo

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to retrieve a specific message from an Amazon SQS queue. The code will call `receive_messages()` and get whatever is in the queue. There is no capability to select or filter which message(s) will be returned.

Frankly, if you are worried that the source message won't delete, then I would recommend implementing re-try code that attempts the deletion again. The inability to delete would most likely be due either to a transient networking error (which a re-try should fix), or the fact that the message is already deleted.